# Why are files seen as modified after fresh clone? When is git add --renormalize . used?

Tags: git, eol, gitattributes

I have a problem with files which are seen as modified after a fresh git clone.

Usecase in my repo:

- all text files shall have `eol=LF`, except `*.txt` files which shall have `eol=CRLF`.

Here's how `.gitattributes` looks like:

```
*       text=auto
*.txt   text  eol=crlf
*.png binary
*.jpg binary
*.bmp binary
```

Here's my tests:

Test 1

- new repo with 2 .txt files (LF.txt and CRLF.txt)

  - `LF.txt`: eol=LF (end of line is `LF` in the whole file)
  - `CRLF.txt`: eol=CRLF (end of line is `CRLF` in the whole file)
- add, commit, push
- add `.gitattributes` (with the content described above): `git add .gitattributes`, commit, push
- fresh clone of repo

  - `LF.txt`: eol is now `CRLF` (as expected)
  - `CRLF.txt` is seen as modified, even if it still has `CRLF` as eol

Test 2

- new repo with 2 .txt files (LF.txt and CRLF.txt)

  - `LF.txt`: eol=LF
  - `CRLF.txt`: eol=CRLF
- add, commit, push
- add `.gitattributes` (with the content described above): `git add --renormalize .`

  - `CRLF.txt` is seen as modified and staged (but there are no content differences and eol is still `CRLF`)
  - `.gitattributes` is still untracked
- track `.gitattributes`: `git add .`
- commit and push
- fresh clone of repo

  - `LF.txt`: eol is now `CRLF` (as expected)
  - `CRLF.txt`: eol is `CRLF` (as in the beginning)
  - repo is clean

#### Additional info

- OS: Windows 10
- git version: 2.20.1.windows.1

#### Questions

1. Test 1: why is CRLF.txt seen as modified after a fresh clone?
2. Test 2: what is `git add --renormalize .` actually doing? Why doesn't it stage `.gitattributes` also?
3. When setting up `.gitattributes` in a repo which already has some history, is it recommended to run `git add --renormalize` in order to avoid modified files after fresh clone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Test 1: why is CRLF.txt seen as modified after a fresh clone?

Because you've lied to git: you've told git that the line endings for `CRLF.txt` in your repository are Unix-style (LF) line endings, but that you want Windows-style (CRLF) line endings *in your working folder*.  That's what the `text` attribute means: normalize the line endings, so that they have Unix-style line endings in the repository.

But your **first** step was to add the file with Windows-style line endings into the repository.

So, git can look at the file on-disk, convert its Windows-style (CRLF) line endings to the normal form (Unix-style LF line endings), and compare the results to what's in the repository.

Those contents don't match.  Thus, it thinks you've modified the file.  *That* is why you renormalize files.

> Test 2: what is git add --renormalize . actually doing?

It updates the files to match what you've claimed in `.gitattributes`.  When you add a `.gitattributes`, you aren't changing the contents of the files on-disk or in the repository.  But you *may* be (and in this case *are*) changing the claims you're making about the way the contents exist in the repository.

If the contents in the repository *aren't* actually *what you claimed*, then `git add --renormalize` will correct that.

> Why doesn't it stage .gitattributes also?

Renormalization only affects files already in the repository, it applies "the 'clean' process freshly to **all tracked files** to forcibly add them again to the index."  (From the git documentation; emphasis mine.)

So it truly only renormalizes *existing* content.

> When setting up .gitattributes in a repo which already has some history, is it recommended to run git add --renormalize in order to avoid modified files after fresh clone?

Yes.