# [Git]: Files shown as modified after fresh clone of a repository

Tags: git

i am pretty new to git world. I have been asked to clone the repository where i notice that few files `crlf.s` are shown as modified after fresh clone of a repository.

```
modified:   llvm/test/MC/AsmParser/preserve-comments-crlf.s
modified:   llvm/test/tools/llvm-mca/X86/directives-handle-crlf.s
modified:   llvm/test/tools/split-file/Inputs/basic-aa.crlf
modified:   llvm/test/tools/split-file/Inputs/basic-bb.crlf
modified:   llvm/test/tools/split-file/basic.crlf.test
```

I have gone through this forum :- [Why are files seen as modified after fresh clone? When is git add --renormalize . used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54592361/why-are-files-seen-as-modified-after-fresh-clone-when-is-git-add-renormalize) , I really don't understand what needs to be done for fix this issue. Could you please help here how can i workaround this issue? And also reason for getting this issue?

My config looks like:-

```
user.name=*****
user.email=*****
credential.helper=cache
http.sslverify=false
core.editor=vim
core.autocrlf=input
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=git@*******:test/hello.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.tk/main.remote=origin
branch.tk/main.merge=refs/heads/tk/main
branch.pt4/comp.remote=origin
branch.pt4/comp.merge=refs/heads/pt4/comp
```

Comment: Do you have any EOL setting there? Show us `git config -l` and `git config --global -l` in the question, please.

Comment: And `git ls-files --eol ...` for the affected files.